# Strange reception of multicast UDP packets (recvfrom)

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, winsock, multicast

**EDIT: Problem explanation modified to make it clearer.**

I have written 2 simple programs:

1. *Client Program*: which sends UDP multicast packets to a
   multicast IP address and port.
2. *Server Program*: which requests membership to the multicast IP, binds to the same port and uses 'recvfrom' to receive those packets. It also prints the content of
   those packets onto console along with source address and port.

Now, I start the 'server' program on Machine_S and the 'client' program on Machine_C. both machines are in the same LAN.

Client's multicast packets reach Machine_S, which I am able to see in Wireshark.
However, 'server' program is not able to read them i.e. the call to *recvfrom* does not return.

NOW, I start another instance of 'client' on Machine_S. As soon as this is done, the 'server' program starts receiving packets from both the clients (from both machines) and prints them out to the console!!

At this point, even if I shut the local 'client' instance on the Machine_S, the 'server' will still continue to receive packets from the remote 'client' on Machine_C.

So in short, the server program seems to receive packets from remote clients only when a local client is also sending packets to the same multicast address and port.

**Client Code:**

```
// COMMON MACROS FOR BOTH CLIENT AND SERVER
#define HELLO_PORT  12345
#define HELLO_GROUP "239.0.0.50"

// after initializing winsock

// create UDP socket
if ((sockid = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {

    printf("SOCKET Error Code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
 }


 // set up destination address
 memset(&addr,0,sizeof(addr));
 addr.sin_family        =   AF_INET;
 addr.sin_addr.s_addr   =   inet_addr(HELLO_GROUP);
 addr.sin_port          =   htons(HELLO_PORT);

 // now just sendto() our destination!
 while (times--) {

     printf("Sent To : %d\n", HELLO_PORT);

     if (sendto (sockid, message, strlen(message)+1, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {

         printf("SENDTO Error Code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
         break;
     }

    Sleep(500);
 }

 closesocket(sockid);

 WSACleanup();
```

---

**Server Code:**

```
// create UDP socket
if ((sockid = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0) {

    printf("SOCKET Error Code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}


// set up local address
memset(&addr,0,sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family         =   AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr    =   htonl (INADDR_ANY);
addr.sin_port           =   htons (HELLO_PORT);

// bind to local address
if (bind(sockid, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {

    printf("BIND Error Code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(sockid);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// join a multicast group 
mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr   =   inet_addr (HELLO_GROUP);
mreq.imr_interface.s_addr   =   htonl (INADDR_ANY);         

if (setsockopt(sockid, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (const char *)&mreq, sizeof(mreq)) < 0) {

    printf("SETSOCKETOPT Error Code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(sockid);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

memset(&addr,0,sizeof(addr));

// now just enter a read-print loop 
while (times--) {

    addrlen =   sizeof(addr);

    if ((nbytes = recvfrom(sockid, msgbuf, MSGBUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &addrlen)) < 0) {

        printf("RECVFROM Error Code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        break;
    }

    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(addr.sin_addr), (PSTR)&address, MSGBUFSIZE);
    srcport = ntohs(addr.sin_port);
    printf("From\t%s\t%d\t", address, srcport);
    puts(msgbuf);

    Sleep(1000);
}

closesocket(sockid);
WSACleanup();
```

Few points to note:

- Each machine has only 1 network interface
- Multicast IP is 239.0.0.50 and port is 12345

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Are you sure that the Multicast IP is correct? I use UDP multicast and I send to 192.168.1.255 within the same network and it works. Can you post what are the IPs of your devices?

Comment: Yes, I am using an address from a range called 'Administratively Scoped IPv4 Multicast addresses' which is meant for private use within an organization. Your IP (192.168.1.255) seems to be a Net Directed Broadcast IP Address. It may be reaching many more hosts apart from those who have joined the multicast group.
(See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address#Administratively_Scoped_IPv4_Multicast_addresses)

Btw IPs of my devices are 192.168.7.33 and 192.168.2.77

Comment: you join the multicast group so it should work. my guess: firewall or routing issue.

Comment: How can it be a routing or firewall issue? I can see all the packets reaching my system via Wireshark. It's only that my 'Server' program is not able to read those packets, when only a remote 'Client' program is running. As soon as I run the same 'Client' on the local system, the 'Server' starts reading all packets.

Comment: Wirkeshark (in promiscuous mode) shows what physically reaches your machine, but it's up to the OS to decide what it shows to each application. e.g.: if you disable ping, the ping packets will still reach your server.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Any suggestions to rectify this issue? and how to ensure that such a thing does not happen in production?

Comment: That was the only "sane" explanation I could come up with, so I thought it's worth a comment. But I have no idea - I don't know much about the windows environment.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath it was a firewall issue. The server program was not allowed to communicate through the firewall. Thanks!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57273/discussion-between-sg1-and-karoly-horvath).